# how to get video thumb nail using video URL in android

Tags: android

Hi i want to get video thumbnail using video url is it possible to  show video thumbnail without downloading video .

```
@Throws(Throwable::class)
fun retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(videoPath: String?): Bitmap? {
    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
    var mediaMetadataRetriever: MediaMetadataRetriever? = null
    try {
        mediaMetadataRetriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(
            videoPath,
            HashMap()
        ) else mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath)
        //   mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
        bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.frameAtTime
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        throw Throwable("Exception in retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)" + e.message)
    } finally {
        mediaMetadataRetriever?.release()
    }
    return bitmap
}
```

calling like this :

```
  retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(postVideoUrl)
```

but when i try to execute i am getting empty bitmap unable to see thumbnail of video
this is my video link https://test-upload-shootup1.s3.amazonaws.com/VIDEO_2023_09_11_17_31_0320230911120105.mp4
please help how i can get video thumbnail in android